# Render forbidden error page if resource not scoped to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to do a query scoped to the current user. If the currently logged in user is not the owner of the resource (an ad) I want to redirect to an error page.

```
class AdController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit]

    def edit
      @ad = current_user.ads.find(params[:id])
      if @ad.blank?
        render status: :forbidden, text: "You do not have access to this page."
      end
    end
end
```

However, I get this error:

`Couldn't find Ad with 'id'=1 [WHERE "ads"."user_id" = $1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in this edit action, you can do it like this:

```
def edit
  @ad = current_user.ads.where(id: params[:id]).first
  if @ad.blank?
    render status: :forbidden, text: "You do not have access to this page."
  end
end
```

or

```
def edit
  @ad = current_user.ads.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  render status: :forbidden, text: "You do not have access to this page."
end
```

If you want to do it globally for more controllers you can add to your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :rescue_from_record_not_found

  def rescue_from_record_not_found
    render status: :forbidden, text: "You do not have access to this page."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! So just to be clear. This works because `.where` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, right? `.find` is actually trying to load the object and therefore produces an error. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No it's because `.find(id)` raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if it does not find record with given `id`. Whereas `.where` returns list of records. If `.where` does not find anything it just return empty array after SQL execution.